# ComponentName/ComponentName.js rather than ComponentName/index.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I prefer to not use index.js as a file name for the main file of a component in React and in node.js, but instead use the name of the parent directory (for example: ...somePath.../ComponentName/ComponentName.js would just be ...somePath.../ComponentName).

Is there any way to have

`require('..somePath../ComponentName')`

and

`import ComponentName from '..somePath../ComponentName'`

work without having to put in the file name too, similar to how you can drop the index.js from the import path.

I am guessing there would be two different solutions for node.js and React, but hopefully there is just one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because of my IDE (I use VScode), but the extension for any file is not needed. This example works in React. Note: Does not work with the styles sheet.

```
Components
├── Header
│   ├── index.js
├── Footer
│   ├── index.js

import Header from '../Header';
import Footer from '../Footer';
```